# Why did Hawkins destroy the Atlantis?

Tags: video-games, unreal

In "Unreal II: The Awakening", the destruction of the Atlantis is the opener to the plot twist, introducing

> Commander Hawkins as the new main adversary.

However, if he tried to convince John Dalton (or the protagonist) to join his side (as later revealed on the Dorian Gray, just before it falls into the star), why would he kill his beloved crew?

Did he just decide to convince John to join him right on the spot, inspired by the gun being pointed at his face?